# Automount not equivelent to mount?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, automounting, autofs

I'm struggling to get automount to work as desired.

If I run the following:

`sudo mount -t nfs server:/path/to/share /path/to/mount_point`

I get the mount appearing fine.

However, if I add the following line to my `auto_master`:

`/path/to/mount_point server:/path/to/share`

it creates the mount point directory but the contents aren't visible.

When I observe the output of the `mount` command, they are different:

- Using the first (manual mount) approach the following entry is returned by `mount`:

  ```
  server:/path/to/share on /path/to/mount_point (nfs)
  ```
- Using `automount` I get the following entry returned by `mount`:

  ```
  map server:/path/to/share on /path/to/mount_point (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
  ```

I assumed that by default, `automount` mounts via NFS and is equivalent to the manual mount.

What is the correct way to use `automount` to acheive the behaviour of the (correctly working) manual mount?

The share is hosted on a Linux NIS domain and I am accessing from a Mac (BSD Unix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/etc/auto.master` file is not the place to set the remote NFS directory path. `/etc/auto.master` expects to be given a map file or directory. From the auto.master man page:

> The  auto.master map is consulted to set up automount managed mount points when the autofs(8) script is invoked or the
>          automount(8) program is run. Each line describes a mount point and refers to an **autofs map** describing file systems  to
>          be mounted under the mount point.

So, create a file called `/etc/auto.remote` (you can change "remote" to whatever you want). Place your mount options in that file. It should have the following format:

```
share_name  mount_options  server:/remote/path/to/share
```

Here's one from my system for example:

```
movies  -rw,soft,intr,bg,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 192.168.0.72:/nfs_shares/movies
```

You can then reference the `auto.remote` file from your `auto.master`:

```
/path/to/mount_point   /etc/auto.remote --timeout 60 --ghost
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer—it worked! Out of interest could you provide some intuition on why those options you set are good practise or useful? I went with just the mount point and share path.

Comment: I adapted them from somewhere or other. The most important one for me is the `soft` option that make sure the daemon will not wait indefintely, causing the system to hang, when the remote server is unavailable.

Comment: What about direct automounts? Have they gone completely?

Comment: What do you mean @Nils? The drive will be mounted as soon as you try to access it (`ls` for example).

Comment: I refer to direct automounts. But there is a little hint in `man auto.master`: format is a subset of the sun automounter format - the same seems to be true for Linux **auto.master**: In Solaris you CAN define such a mount directly in auto.master without the use of an indirect map.